# Where do I find the cassette tape in the Crimson Room? And what is the key for?

Tags: crimson-room

I've already found these:

1. small red box
2. key
3. golden key
4. silver key
5. metal stick
6. power supply cable
7. thin ring
8. heavy ring
9. battery
10. CD
11. memo

Where do I find the cassette tape in the Crimson Room? And what is the key for?